# Why don't my divs display block

Tags: html, css, block, display

Here is my CSS document: http://brandonholmes.net/scheduleus.css

Can someone please explain why the 'nav' divs and overlap each other and the 'fixerheader' div even though both are set to 'display: block'?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the code in question...

```
#nav {
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
}

#fixedheader{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background: #000000;
 padding: 0px 3px;
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please Provide your code in the question

Comment: The code can be found in the linked document, but sure.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed` is completely independent from everything else. Its position is only determined by the top/bottom/left/right parameters in relation to the browser window, it takes no space in the document flow.

Also `position: absolute` takes no space in the document flow. The difference to `fixed`is, that it is anchored to its parent element concerning its position.

Therefore both will easily overlap other elements, which is likely the cause of your problem.

`display: block` doesn't change anything in that respect.

Comment: So what is the best way to create three divs: one that acts as a header and spans the entire top of the page, and two that fall directly underneath it, avoiding overlap, and fit themslves to the size of their content?

I considered defining height/width but as the content will vary in size I don't want to have ugly design later on if the content is too much for the defined size of the div.

Comment: without any HTML code it is nearly impossible to give you advice - what you ask in your comment is really too broad to give you a satisfying answer

Answer (score 0):

Without html it is not possible to answer your question, but defining a height could solve your problem. try to give a fixed height of 100px for example.